# Design idea of "Turn" in chess

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a chess program, and I am at the stage of implementing the game loop.

To implement player Turn in chess, I want to get some advice on how to do it efficiently.

So, this is how my chess with GUI works so far:

I generate a class called BoardGUI(JPanel) with a size of 8x8 and place a class called TileGUI(JPanel) on each grid.

I also added a MouseListener on TileGUI and wrote all functions regarding the Piece's movement on the board.

All tiles that have a Piece also contains the information of the Piece (color, type).

My initial thought of implementing the "Turn" is to create an integer called turn, initialized to 0, and make the Black Piece movable when the turn integer is an odd number and make the White Piece movable when the turn integer is an even number.

This is the best idea, or will there be a more clever way to do this?

Comment: *"more clever way to do this*" - doesn't always equate to "better". You could use a `enum` which would make the code easier to read, by the concept would remain the same

Comment: Golden rule of software development: simpler = better

Comment: or a boolean called whiteTurn. true at start of the game. then after each move, whiteTurn = !whiteTurn; you could count moves in an integer anyway, but it would be a separate concept to who's turn it is. decoupling it from the actual move counter means you could set up different board scenarios where black moves first and still have accurate turn state and move count.

Comment: From your description, your design seems too much coupled to the user interface and could cause you problems later. For instance, how is your program going to check the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_repetition) chess rule? IMHO it would be better to have an "engine" to which you provide the positions of pieces along with a turn number, and have other class/es do the visual representation of the board.

Comment: @Guillem thanks for the advice, but I actually do have all engine-related stuff implemented in a different package.